# How do I default a business process ribbon to minimized upon opening a record in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Thank you very much. I couldn't find a setting inside dynamics CRM or a solution anywhere on google.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the JavaScript library available for free on Codeplex from Carsten Groth, MVP:
https://bpfhelper.codeplex.com/